# How to create a continuous flow of water?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have built a water slide and pool and I want to make a animation of the water running down the slide and into the pool. The problem is I need the water to be created at the top and go away at the bottom to create a continues stream of water. What would be the best way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need an *Inflow* object and an *Outflow* object.

1. Setup your domain object. Add a cube that encloses the entire area you want the water to go (don't make it to big though, as the larger it is the more CPU time your bake will require). Then add a fluid modifier in the *Physics* panel with the type set to *Domain*
2. Add the inflow object at the top of the slide and the outflow object at the bottom. Add fluid modifiers with the appropriate types to the objects.
3. Add an *Obstacle* type fluid modifier to the slide and anything else you want to collide with the fluid.
4. Bake

Comment: The fluid obstacles aren't holding the water, do they need to be on the same layer? EDIT: Moving them to the same layer did not help. The water just keeps falling until  it hits the domain

Comment: Here is the .Blend https://mega.co.nz/#!1MkVGRZB!Aaf28mAZx7fv5kWEG6MENmawY84FaPQw45kPF3-4ETc Also the inflow object is not working

Comment: @qwertyk31 They need to have some thickness. Try adding and applying a solidify modifier. As for the inflow object, it's too small for the current resolution you are baking at. Either scale it up, or increase the resolution

Comment: That still has no efect

Comment: @qwertyk31 Strange.. It's working for me. Did you apply the modifier?

Comment: Applying the modifier held the water, but the inflow object still does not work.

Comment: @qwertyk31 It's still working for me. [Here's a blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25720)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for where I'd find more specific answers for how the water modifier works?

Comment: @JustWondering If you have questions about a specific aspect or thing you want to do, you can always ask here. Otherwise, there are plenty of tutorials around (such as [this one](https://www.blendernation.com/2016/12/24/comprehensive-tutorial-fluid-simulation/)), and [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/index.html). For more info about the the internal workings (is that what you are after?), I believe it uses a [lattice-boltzmann method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_Boltzmann_methods)